# How to do masking in android to get this effect?

Tags: android, masking

http://www.flashfridge.com/tutorial.asp?ID=135

I want similar masking effect in android. I want to move a blurred oval as user moves his finger and I want that oval to mask underlying bitmap so that i can see only that portion of bitmap, but do not know how to get this effect in android.

Comment: use `BitmaoShader` in your custom `View` / `Drawable`

Comment: Hey bro, Thanks for reply but I am not expert in android so can you please help me with some code.

Comment: see http://www.curious-creature.com/2012/12/13/android-recipe-2-fun-with-shaders/

Comment: Thanks bro, It helped me a lot. Can I contact you if I want any help ?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `PorterDuff.Mode.DST_IN` to achieve this:

```
public static Bitmap getMaskedBitmap(Resources res, int sourceResId, int maskResId) {
  BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
  if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB) {
    options.inMutable = true;
  }
  options.inPreferredConfig = Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888;
  Bitmap source = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(res, sourceResId, options);
  Bitmap bitmap;
  if (source.isMutable()) {
    bitmap = source;
  } else {
    bitmap = source.copy(Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888, true);
    source.recycle();
  }
  bitmap.setHasAlpha(true);
  Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bitmap);
  Bitmap mask = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(res, maskResId);
  Paint paint = new Paint();
  paint.setXfermode(new PorterDuffXfermode(PorterDuff.Mode.DST_IN));
  canvas.drawBitmap(mask, 0, 0, paint);
  mask.recycle();
  return bitmap;
}
```

Full tutorial [here](http://www.piwai.info/transparent-jpegs-done-right/).

Comment: But how can I make it interactive.